# initializing parallel chains in rjags

Tags: r, jags

I'm doing some ghetto parallelization in jags through rjags.

I've been using the function parallel.seeds to obtain RNG states to intialize the RNG's (example below). However, I don't understand why multiple integers are returned for each RNG. In the documentation it says that when you intialize .RNG.state is supposed to be a numeric vector with length one.

Furthermore, sometimes when I try to do this R crashes with no error generated. When I give up and just let it generate the seed for the chain on it's own, the model runs fine. Does this mean I am using the wrong .RNG.state? Any insight would be appreciated, as I am planning to scale up this model in the future.

```
> parallel.seeds("base::BaseRNG", 3)
[[1]]
[[1]]$.RNG.name
[1] "base::Wichmann-Hill"

[[1]]$.RNG.state
[1]  3891 16261 19841


[[2]]
[[2]]$.RNG.name
[1] "base::Marsaglia-Multicarry"

[[2]]$.RNG.state
[1]  408065014 1176110892


[[3]]
[[3]]$.RNG.name
[1] "base::Super-Duper"

[[3]]$.RNG.state
[1] -848274653  175424331
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between .RNG.seed (which is a vector of length one, and the thing you can specify to jags.model to e.g. ensure MCMC samples are repeatable) and .RNG.state (which is a vector of length depending on the pRNG algorithm).  It is possible that these got mixed up in the docs somewhere - can you tell me where you read this so I can make sure it is fixed for JAGS/rjags 4?

Regarding the crashing - some more details would be needed to help you with that I'm afraid.  I assume that it is the JAGS model that crashes, and not your R session that terminates, and after the model has been running for a while?  A reproducible example would help a lot.

By the way - when you say 'scale up' - if you are planning to make use of > 4 chains I would strongly recommend you load the lecuyer module (see ?parallel.seeds examples at the bottom).

Matt

Comment: Yep I was getting confused about the RNG.state versus RNG.seed. I thought that the point of the parallel.seeds function was to give you seeds that you could then supply when starting chains. So I specified the RNG.state when I initialized a chain, which crashed my R session. So can I just specify a RNG.name and use some random integer for RNG.seed?

Comment: Yes - just a plain old integer will do for RNG.seed (I like to use the date I wrote the script, e.g. .RNG.seed=2015-10-16).  This is mostly for reproducibility purposes.  The point of parallel.seeds is to give you initial RNG states (i.e. the full internal state) so that you can safely run multiple chains in parallel, which is for avoiding problems with parallel chains not being fully independent when using the same RNG type.  Note that it is not (currently) possible to do both - i.e. parallel.seeds can't be given a .RNG.seed argument.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is a bit confusing; under ?jags.model we see that .RNG.seed should be a vector of length 1, but parallel.seeds() returns .RNG.state which is usually > 1.  [The state space for the Mersenne Twister algorithm has 624 integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister), and that is the length of the vector when you do

```
parallel.seeds("base::BaseRNG",4)
```

to make sure you see all 4 types of RNG.  [Similarly the state space of the Wichmann-Hill generator has 3 integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wichmann-Hill), and I'm sure similar research would reveal the state spaces for the other two are longer than 1.

For my own edification I mocked up an example using the LINE data in rjags:

```
data(LINE)

LINE$model() ## edit and save to line.r
data = LINE$data()

line = jags.model("line.r",data=data)
line.samples <- jags.samples(LINE, c("alpha","beta","sigma"),n.iter=1000)
line.samples
inits = parallel.seeds("base::BaseRNG", 3) # a list of lists
inits[[1]]$tau = 1
inits[[1]]$alpha = 3
inits[[1]]$beta = 1
inits[[2]]$tau = .1
inits[[2]]$alpha = .3
inits[[2]]$beta = .1
inits[[3]]$tau = 10
inits[[3]]$alpha = 10
inits[[3]]$beta = 5

line = jags.model("line.r",data=data,inits=inits,n.chains=3)
line.samples <- jags.samples(line, c("alpha","beta","sigma"),n.iter=1000)
line2 = jags.model("line.r",data=data,inits=inits,n.chains=3)
line.samples2 <- jags.samples(line2, c("alpha","beta","sigma"),n.iter=1000)
all(line.samples$alpha-line.samples2$alpha < 0.00000001) ## TRUE
```

So the results are entirely repeatable, which is cool.

To understand the conditions under which R is crashing, I'd need to know the results of sessionInfo() on your computer, plus more details of the circumstances (e.g. what JAGS model are you running?). I just did:

```
for (i in 1:100){parallel.seeds("base::BaseRNG",4)}
```

and my computer didn't crash. For reference:

```
sessionInfo()
# R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
# Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
# Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
# 
# locale:
#   [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
# [2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
# [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
# [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
# [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
# 
# attached base packages:
#   [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
# [6] methods   base     
# 
# other attached packages:
#   [1] rjags_3-14       coda_0.17-1      mlogit_0.2-4    
# [4] maxLik_1.2-4     miscTools_0.6-16 Formula_1.2-1   
# 
# loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#   [1] grid_3.1.3      lattice_0.20-30 lmtest_0.9-33  
# [4] MASS_7.3-39     sandwich_2.3-3  statmod_1.4.21 
# [7] tools_3.1.3     zoo_1.7-12
```

That shows the version of R and rjags that I'm using.

Comment: Mm. Perhaps I wasn't clear. R crashes upon subsequently running a model using a single integer value obtained from the parallel.seeds function, NOT upon running the parallel.seeds function. I've now tried using the entire vector supplied for a given RNG as the RNG seed when I initialize my model, and this works fine. Hopefully the typo is fixed in the next release!

Comment: also, by the way, it looks like the RNG states have variable vector lengths. You can see this by running "parallel.seeds" a few times in a row.

Comment: @Drew, OK, well in that case I can't help with the crash diagnosis without knowing about the code that causes the crash. I'm not sure the state vector lengths for a given RNG change, but the order of the RNGs in the results does. Thanks for the accept!

Comment: @atiretoo - you say in your post that there is a typo in the documentation regarding the length of the vector for $.RNG.state - can you let me know where this is so I can correct it for JAGS 4? I have had a read of the relevant documentation but I can't spot anything wrong!

Comment: @MattDenwood -- I think the statement that has me and the OP confused is on the help page for jags.model, under the section Random Number Generators it says that the initial seed should be a vector of length 1, but parallel.seeds() returns .RNG.state, which is length > 1. However jags.model is happy to take the output of parallel.seeds(), see my edited answer.

Comment: @Drew when you say -- "this works fine" did you mean that it fixed the crash as well?

Comment: @atiretoo I think this is just confusion between .RNG.seed and .RNG.state as I said in my answer.  The .RNG.seed can be supplied to jags.model as an argument, but the model itself always stores .RNG.state (see e.g. data(LINE); LINE$state(internal=TRUE)) - this same list can also be passed to jags.model.  But .RNG.state and .RNG.seed are in fact different things - the former has variable length, the latter always length 1 as documented.  The parallel.seeds function also returns a .RNG.state - taking a .RNG.seed argument will eventually be implemented for parallel.seeds but it not currently.

Comment: ps.  Thanks for the clarification - I have added the following to the RNG section of jags.model .....         
  
Note that it is also possible to specify .RNG.state rather than 
.RNG.seed - see for example parallel.seeds.